# How to select a specific data from the database and render it to a django template?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a website using Django 2.2.1,So the problem I currently have is I have a model named "Product".
I also have a template named "product_list.html".
My "views.py" file is:-

```
from .models import Product
from .forms import ProductForm
# Create your views here.


def product_detail_view(request):
    obj = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
      "title": obj,
      "description": obj,
      "price": obj
#context = {
#    'object': obj
}
return render_to_response("product_list.html",context)
```

My models.py file :-

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = models.TextField(null=True)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
```

My product_list.html file :-

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Product List</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<ul>
  <li>
          {{ title }}
  </li>
  <li>
          {{ obj.title }}
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   {% for prod in title %}
  <li>
      {{ prod.title | upper }}
  </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul>
 {% for prod in description %}
  <li>
       {{ prod.description|default:"nothing" }}
  </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul>
 {% for prod in price %}
  <li>
       {{ prod.price }}
  </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul>
 {% for prod in price %}
  <li>
       {{ prod.title }}
       {{ prod.description }}
       {{ prod.price }}
  </li>
   {% endfor %}
 </ul>


{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The output I get is:-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmogdmgerf3cbu6/Image%205-7-19%20at%2010.11%20PM.jpg?dl=0

So the Issue is how can i select for example:-
i only want the title and description of product 1 .
(( As i have tried the same in my product_list.html file...
   I have tried both {{ title }} and {{ obj.title }}
   both of them couldn't provide me with the data i wanted from the
   database.))

i was only able to render and get that data when i was using {{ for }}
with the function objects.all().

The other option i see is to change my view function .. and update it with 
"objects.get(id)"

but then i would have to make multiple views if i am not wrong.

Are there any other function or any other django template language filters that could provide me with the same result while still using the "objects.all()"
function.

or are there any other mistakes or Errors I have ?

Comment: Your view is called `product_detail_view` yet your template is called `product_list.html`. Could you clarify whether you want to see a list view of all your products (or a subset of them) or a detailed view of a single product?

Comment: Hello Mihai, I would want to have a detailed view of a single product, as in just that product while using the objects.all() function (for example - i only want title and price of product 1 only) ...I can get the detailed view of a product if i change the view function to objects.get(id). But then its limited to that product only that is the "id" of that product .

Comment: Why not do something similar to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views#Book_detail_page), where you capture the ID of the product you want to display details for from the URL, that way you can have a single view that allows you to view any specific product you want by specifying the ID in the URL and using `objects.get(id)` in the view to retrieve the object you want? I don't understand your requirement to retrieve all objects, only to print out the details for only one of them.

Comment: ohh Thank You! I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def product_detail_view(request):
    obj = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
      "title": obj,
      "description": obj,
      "price": obj
#context = {
#    'object': obj
}
return render_to_response("product_list.html",context)
```

The **title**, **description** and **price** you have specified have the same contents. However, the contents that will be fetched from the database contain titles, descriptions and prices. So, you have to specify the contents that you want to fetch from the databses.
Meaning when can say:

```
data=Product.objects.all()
   context={"data":data}
```

then you have to specify the titles, descriptions, prices in the templates.
For instance

```
{% for datum in data  %}
   {{ datum.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

[visit this link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/display+data+from+database+in+django)